# How to write bash script in Makefile

Tags: bash, make

I have a directory structure like this:

```
`-- dev
    |-- example-object
    |   |-- example-object.tex
    |   `-- example-template
    |       |-- example-template.tex
    |       `-- instances
    |           `-- example-instance.tex
    `-- example-object2
        |-- example-object2.tex
        `-- example-template2
            |-- example-template2.tex
            `-- instances
                `-- example-instance2.tex
```

I'd like to have a directory with only these files:

```
`-- src
    |-- xcv.example-object.tex
    |-- xcv.example-object.example-template.tex
    |-- xcv.example-object.example-template.example-instance.tex
    |-- xcv.example-object2.tex
    |-- xcv.example-object2.example-template2.tex
    `-- xcv.example-object2.example-template2.example-instance2.tex
```

This bash script does what I want, but other than copy/pasting it into a Makefile, I can't figure out how to use Make's functionality to do the same:

```sh
mkdir -p src/
dest=$(pwd)/src

for object in $(find dev ! -path dev -type d -maxdepth 1); do
    oname=$(basename "${object}")
    echo cp "${oname}.tex" "${dest}"/xcv."${oname}".tex
    for template in $(find "${object}" ! -path "${object}" -type d -maxdepth 1); do
        tname=$(basename "${template}")
        echo cp "${tname}.tex" "${dest}"/xcv."${oname}"."${tname}".tex
        for instance in $(find "${template}"/instances -type f); do
            iname=$(basename "${instance}")
            echo cp "${iname}.tex" "${dest}"/xcv."${oname}"."${tname}"."${iname}"
        done
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write multi-line `bash` scripts in `Makefile`. Every line is executed in new shell so you will lose context. Also the variables are evaluated as `make` variables. Rather store your code in separate `bash` script and run that from `Makefile`. It is not worth to abuse your `bash` script nor `make` to do that job.

If you really want to have it in your `Makefile`, you need to make it one-line and escape the dollars in variables.

Example that will not work:

```
$ cat Makefile
test: 
    VAR="YES";
    echo "x${VAR}";
$ make
VAR="YES";
echo "x";
x
```

Escaped:

```
$ cat Makefile
test: 
    VAR="YES"; \
    echo "x$${VAR}";
jakuje@E6430:/tmp/test$ make
VAR="YES"; \
echo "x${VAR}";
xYES
```

Comment: The ``\`` syntax is exactly what I was referring to with copy/paste :-) I'm looking for a solution with [`foreach`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html) and the like.

Comment: so then I really didn't get your question. Or you expect I will rewrite your code to work in Makefile?

Comment: I'm continuing to try to figure out the Makefile approach and will edit-in my best attempt when I feel it's as far as I can go, but yes. Even the basic idea of mapping functionality onto files/folders in a directory would basically answer the question.